# Query Firestore collection by object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I create a collection called "books", in it I made an object (aka. dict) called "users". That object looks like this:

```
users: {
    5PPCTcdHOtdYjGFr7gbCEsiMaWG3: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}
```

Now I want to query all books that belong to a certain user. I tried this:

```
this.db
  .collection('books')
  .where(`users.${this.state.currentUser.uid}`, '>', 0)
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      ...
```

I never get any documents returned. I'm sure the there is something it should match.

[image: screenshot of Firestore console]

To check my sanity, if I remove the `where(...)` part, I do get documents. Just that I get documents for all users.

I console logged that string in the `.where()` and it looks right.

Comment: As a short term solution I loop over all documents and compare each `doc.data().users`. But it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You’re query is wrong because you are comparing a date object with a number, therefore two different things. You can check it by running these two lines of code below.

```
  console.log(typeof(firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()))
  console.log(typeof(0))
```

So you have two options:

1 - You can compare date objects with data objects like below.

```
this.db
  .collection('books')
  .where(`users.${this.state.currentUser.uid}`, '>', new Date(0))
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      ...
```

2 - Or you can save your date in milliseconds and compare it with a number.

```
users: {
    5PPCTcdHOtdYjGFr7gbCEsiMaWG3: new Date().getTime();
}

 this.db
      .collection('books')
      .where(`users.${this.state.currentUser.uid}`, '>', 0)
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't get this to work with `.where()` either, but it seems to work using `.orderBy()`, replacing:

```
.where(`users.${this.state.currentUser.uid}`, '>', 0)
```

with

```
.orderBy(`users.${this.state.currentUser.uid}`)
```

Comment: yeah it seems orderBy just by itself is enough, but just who knows it might change using new Date(0) is safer